# Asp.net mvc master page and razor layout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, layout, asp.net-mvc-4, master-pages

The razor view engine has not master pages. I have a picture that created in aspx view engine.
How can I create this simply in razor view engine.
[image]

Comment: With a layout? http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx

Comment: As Ant said in razor you can use layout pages instead of mater pages. So whatever you did with mater pages you shoul be able to repeat it by using layout pages.